# Wild Card Search in Listbox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

In my C# window application I need wild card search on list box.
i.e If I write some text in textbox it should be auto selected in that list box.

List box is binding using datatable e.g `lstVendor.datasource = l_dtTable`

Findstring() function is finding match only for starting string. But I need if match find at any position in particular text then it should be highlighted.

I am Using below code but not getting index/or even `lstVendor.selecteditem = "string"` not working.

Indexof() always return -1

```
string final = "";
foreach (Object lstItem in lstVendor.Items)
{
    string s = ((DataRowView)(lstItem)).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();

    if (s.ToLower().Contains(txtVendor.Text.ToLower()))
    {
        int i = lstVendor.Items.IndexOf(s);

        final += s + ",";
    }
}

string[] l_strArrVendorList = final.TrimEnd(',').Split(',');
for (int Counter = 0; Counter < l_strArrVendorList.Length; Counter++)
{
    lstVendor.SelectedItem = l_strArrVendorList[Counter];
}
```

Comment: Does [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11556/Converting-Wildcards-to-Regexes) helps?

Comment: No, every time getting -1 as index and can't see any item selected in list even array contain string having matching text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching may return multiple matched items, this code will find the first matched items:

```
var firstMatched = listBox1.Items.Cast<DataRowView>()
                           .Where(v=>Convert.ToString(v.Row[0]).ToLower()
                                            .Contains(txtVendor.Text.ToLower()))
                           .FirstOrDefault();
if(firstMatched != null) listBox1.SelectedItem = firstMatched;
```

You can remove the `FirstOrDefault()` to get the list of matched items and implement some navigation through the matched items.

For VS 2000 support, you have to use this extension class:

```
public static class EnumerableExtension {
   public static IEnumerable<T> Cast<T>(this System.Collections.IEnumerable source){
     foreach(var item in source)
        yield return (T)item;
   }
}
```

My code above should work OK for you, but looks like you just want your code to be fixed instead, here is the fixed code for you:

```
//Note that you need to set SelectionMode for your listBox like this:
lstVendor.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;
foreach (var lstItem in lstVendor.Items.Cast<DataRowView>()) {
  string s = lstItem.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
  if (s.ToLower().Contains(txtVendor.Text.ToLower())) {        
    lstVendor.SelectedItems.Add(lstItem);
  }
}
```

Comment: will  VS 2000 will support this? Not sure

Comment: listbox1.selctedItem is not working for this particular code segment even for some hardcode value. But Selectedindex is working.

Comment: @user2365758 you need VS 2008 or higher, what time is it that you still use VS 2000? SelectedItem works OK, what **hardcoded** value did you try? Remember that the value should be a **DataRowView**, not a string.

Comment: @user2365758 see my update (with a class extension), that will help you use my previous code in VS 2000.

Comment: I m also working on higher version...but that particular proj is very old..Any way.

In my code sample when 
lstVendor.SelectedItem = l_strArrVendorList[Counter];

Please make changes in this so that i can see highlighted items.
Thx

Comment: @user2365758 what's your problem now? what's wrong with that code? if that's your problem, your question was asked for another thing (search?)

Comment: @user2365758 even I fixed that for you, your code won't work, your code to find the items is wrong, `lstVendor.Items.IndexOf(s);` will always return `-1`, your listbox Items are `DataRowViews`, not `strings`. Why don't you try to understand? What's wrong with my code? Have you not even tried it yet?

Comment: My question is same i was asking before....why my code segment always returning -1 as index and what change it required to make item selected....

Comment: @Elliana my previous comment explained why it returns `-1`, your listbox Items are `DataRowViews` and `IndexOf` requires a `DataRowView` to have a change returning something not `-1`, otherwise it will always return `-1`.

Comment: @Elliana in fact, your code is using `for-loop`, while my code uses `LINQ`, it's much simpler and more concise.

Comment: Oho sorry delay...I just see ur comments after adding my . I m trying ur code.

Comment: @Elliana now, I've also added the code using `for-loop` for you, your code has many things wrong, just don't try to implement it more.